# I want to make users have full access only on ONE rds instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-iam

I tried using this policy:

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",  
  "Statement":[{
    "Effect":"Allow",
    "Action":"rds:*",
    "Resource":"arn:aws:rds:sa-east-1:442617300818:db:databasename"
    }]
}
```

And the response is:

> User: arn:aws:iam::442617300818:user/wa-DB-developers is not
>   authorized to perform: rds:DescribeDBInstances (Service: AmazonRDS;
>   Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID:
>   5f1e86c6-8145-11e4-9598-27c541a5a3a7)

THANKS!

Answer (score 4):

Policies can be debugged by using the [IAM Policy Simulator](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UsingPolicySimulatorGuide/iam-policy-simulator-guide.html).

The simulator allows you to select a User, an Action (eg DescribeDbInstances) and a resource, and then determine whether the User is allowed to call that action on that resource.

In your specific case, since the policy only grants permission on a specific RDS instance, a call to `DescribeDBIntances` without specifying a specific instance will fail.

For example, from the CLI this will fail:

```
aws rds describe-db-instances
```

However, this will work:

```
aws rds describe-db-instances --db-instance-identifier databasename
```

This is because you have not granted permission to view all databases. Querying only the specific database to which the policy has granted access will succeed.

Comment: Is it possible to allow the user to perform `describe-db-instances` but limit his result list only to instances specified by the policy, e.g. few `db-instance-identifiers`?

Comment: The `describe-db-instances` command is an "all or nothing" API call. If somebody has permissions to make the call, then all data is returned. See: [Amazon RDS Actions That Don't Support Resource-Level Permissions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAM.ResourcePermissions.html)

Comment: That's quite unfortunate for me. I wish I could specify in EC2 Instance Profile(in the attached role) which RDS instances should it see. Then I would be able to programatically discover them with Java SDK with **no outside information** delivered to the application. Right now, the application must get list of "matching" `db-instance-identifier` to filter the list. Otherwise it won't know which RDS should it connect to when the list becomes huge. Am I missing something? Are there any workarounds to my use case?

Comment: @programming_and_math Feel free to ask a new question with details of your need.

Comment: Good idea, I have asked it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55937597/aws-rds-describedbinstances-limit-result-list-only-to-specific-instance-using

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. This way lets the user see all the databases, then deny access to the databases you don't want the user to make adjustments to. The user will be able to see the other instances but will not be able to effect them.  They will **not** even be able to see the logs, tags, etc.

```
   {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "rds:*",
                "cloudwatch:DescribeAlarms",
                "cloudwatch:GetMetricStatistics",
                "ec2:DescribeAccountAttributes",
                "ec2:DescribeAvailabilityZones",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
                "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
                "sns:ListSubscriptions",
                "sns:ListTopics",
                "logs:DescribeLogStreams",
                "logs:GetLogEvents"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "rds:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:rds:eu-west-1:accountIDofIAMUser:db:instancename"
        }
    ]
}
```

The only issue you might have is if you have many instances that you need to remove access to, other than that and as long as you are ok with the user seeing the overall view of the other databases you should be good to go.