# AWS RDS DescribeDbInstances - limit result list only to specific instance using IaaC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, terraform

I am trying to provision an architecture with Terraform and ensure that applications have as little knowledge about anything going around them as possible.

My goal is to have an app that uses Amazon's SDK to ask which RDS instances are available for it and then to connect to one of them. This way, no outside information(`db-instance-identifier` or `Tag`) is required.

The application would just describe the RDS instances, and since EC2 on which it runs would have been given permissions by Terraform only to specific RDS, it would have gotten just one result from the `describe-db-instances`. Then, by using RDS IAM auth mechanism, the application would connect to the DB and serve its purpose.

Though from what I have seen e.g. [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27425769/i-want-to-make-users-have-full-access-only-on-one-rds-instance/27437404?noredirect=1#comment98525173_27437404) and AWS RDS documentation `describe-db-instances` is "all or nothing" type of command. IAM Policy given to IAM Role on the EC2 Instance Profile must have `Resource: "*"`. But then, the description contains all the RDS instances, not just the one EC2 should be allowed to connect to. **The application has no way to distinguish which of the `n` results from instances list should it use.**

On the other hand, when you limit `describe-db-instances` to specific resource, then the only way to describe without failure is to add the `db-instance-identifier` to the request:

```
aws rds describe-db-instances --db-instance-identifier databasename
```

But then, the application needs to retrieve the `db-instance-identifier` from the "outside", and that fails to meet my requirements too.

Perhaps I am mistaken in some parts of my reasoning, but is it even possible to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

If the RDS instances are provisioned using the same Terraform deployment, you could do something like the following:

```
locals {
  allowed_rds_nodes = aws_db_instance.foo.*.id
}
```

This is a basic, high-level abstraction, but you could pass a list of IDs of the DB nodes to the Terraform module/code responsible for creating the EC2 instances.

If the RDS nodes already exist, and the Terraform code is only responsible for the EC2 instances, that is a bit trickier.

You are correct in that the only valid query or filter mechanism for RDS instances(currently) is name-based. You would need to use a data source, and enforce some kind of rudimentary naming regex on your DB nodes.

```
data "aws_db_instance" "allowed_rds_nodes" {
  db_instance_identifier = "some-foo-bar"
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately RDS are deployed in another Terraform module. For now the only way for me would be to follow some kind of convention with tags or identifiers, so that app `service_01` looks for database with the tag/identifier `service_01`. But that still requires (implicit and "hardcoded") knowledge inside the application, which I was hoping to remove.

Comment: If the RDS are deployed via Terraform, that remote state(if it exists) can be defined as a data source and parsed, but yes there is going to be some requirement of implicit knowledge, some kind of regex around what is allowed and not.